# Deserializing JSON with Gson

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I get a server response with complex objects that are build in the following way:

```
json array of object type A with
           { jsonobject with a json array of object type B
                 }
```

I'm trying to deserialize it to my object typeA and object typeB like the ones in the below example:

```
public class ObjectA{
   String a;
   int b;
   ArrayList<ObjectB> list;
}

public class ObjectB{
   String a1;
   int b2;
   String c3;
}
```

This is an example of my JSON

```
[
   {
      "a": "a",
      "b": 1,
      "list": [
         {
            "a1": "a1",
            "b2": 2,
            "c3": "c3"
         },
         {
            "a1": "a1",
            "b2": 2,
            "c3": "c3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "a": "a",
      "b": 1,
      "list": [
         {
            "a1": "a1",
            "b2": 2,
            "c3": "c3"
         },
         {
            "a1": "a1",
            "b2": 2,
            "c3": "c3"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How do I deserialize this?

Comment: Canu deswerialize this in java?

Comment: i want to deserialize it with java, the question is how ?

Comment: Yes You can deserialize using gson.. String jsonInputStr = "your json string";

Gson gson = new Gson();

List<ObjectA> persons = gson.fromJson(jsonInputStr, new TypeToken<List<ObjectA>>(){}.getType());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a class hierarchy, you can take advantage of it and let Gson do all the work for you. To explain better what I mean, I prepared a code ready to run:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q18123430;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Q18123430 {

    public static class ObjectA {
        String a;
        int b;
        ArrayList<ObjectB> list;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ObjectA [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", list=" + list + "]";
        }

    }

    public static class ObjectB {
        String a1;
        int b2;
        String c3;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ObjectB [a1=" + a1 + ", b2=" + b2 + ", c3=" + c3 + "]";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[{  a:\"a\",b:1,list:  [{a1:\"a1\",b2:2,c3:\"c3\"},{a1:\"a1\",b2:2,c3:\"c3\"}]}, {  a:\"a\",b:1,list:  [{a1:\"a1\",b2:2,c3:\"c3\"},{a1:\"a1\",b2:2,c3:\"c3\"}]}]";
        Type listOfObjectA = new TypeToken<List<ObjectA>>() {
        }.getType();

        Gson g = new Gson();
        ArrayList<ObjectA> result = g.fromJson(json, listOfObjectA);
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

and this is my execution result:

```
[ObjectA [a=a, b=1, list=[ObjectB [a1=a1, b2=2, c3=c3], ObjectB [a1=a1, b2=2, c3=c3]]], ObjectA [a=a, b=1, list=[ObjectB [a1=a1, b2=2, c3=c3], ObjectB [a1=a1, b2=2, c3=c3]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(); //This is your outer most JSONARRAY
for(int i=0;i<jsArray.length;i++)
{
     JSONObject innerJsonObj = jsArray.getJSONObject(i);//this is your inner jsonobject
     Log.v("a",innserJsonObj.getString("a"));
     Log.v("b",innserJsonObj.getString("b"));
     Log.v("list",innserJsonObj.getString("list")); // you have to use another loop to deal with this json array
     //to generate json array you can use:
     JSONArray innerJsonArray = new JSONArray(innserJsonObj.getString("list"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize in Java using Gson library in a single line as below

```
String jsonInputStr = "your json string";

Gson gson = new Gson();
List<ObjectA> objectList = gson.fromJson(jsonInputStr, new TypeToken<List<ObjectA>>(){}.getType());
```